# Node JS validation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to NodeJS, and have written a method to create a new user, but I need to validate the parameters passed. I'm attempting make sure that an email is not registered twice. This doesn't work, because it checks if the error array is empty before the self.emailExists() callback is completed, how do I fix this?

```
userSchema.statics.buildUser = function(email, name, cb) {

    var self = this;

    var user = new this();
    var errors = [];

    if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
        errors.push({
            'err': -1,
            'msg': 'Invalid email'  
        });
    } else {
        self.emailExists(email, function(exists) {
            if (exists) {
                errors.push({
                    'err': -1,
                    'msg': 'Email address is already in use'
                });
            } else {
                user.email = email;
            }

        });
    }

    if (!validator.trim(name).length > 0) {
        errors.push({
            'err': -1,
            'msg': 'Invalid name'
        });
    } else {
        user.name = name;
    }


    if (errors.length != 0) {
        cb(errors, null);
    } else {
        cb(false, user);
    }
}
```

My emailExists method is:

```
userSchema.statics.emailExists = function(email, cb) {
    var self = this;

    self.count({email: email}, function (err, count) {
        cb(count > 0);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to restructure your code to put the errors.length check in emailExists() callback. Try [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) and Promises to manage asynchronous calls better